# ContourPlot of Or expression

Tags: plotting

How can I get the following to produce a plot of the two circles?

```
ContourPlot[Or[x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1/4], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: `ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1/4}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` ( I never seen Or used like this, so not sure what you meant by it)

Comment: Mathematically, to get $f = 0 \vee g = 0$, you multiply the functions $f\,g=0$, i.e., `(x^2 + y^2 - 1)(x^2 + y^2 - 1/4) == 0`.  But the answers below give better computational / *Mathematica* solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way of thinking about using `||` makes perfect sense to me as well, but the fact is that `ContourPlot` simply doesn't use this syntax.  When using equations with `ContourPlot`, don't interpret `x^2 + y^2 == 1` as a statement (statements can be joined with logical operators), just as a "curve" described by an implicit equation.  If you need several curves plotted with one command, put them in a list, as in bbgodfrey's answer.

Since version 10, `ImpicitRegion` can use the syntax you're looking for though:

```
RegionPlot[ImplicitRegion[ x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 1/4, {x, y}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`x^2 + y^2 == 1 || x^2 + y^2 == 1/4` is a statement that can be `True` or `False` depending on the values of `x`.  `ImplicitRegion` represents the domain in the $(x,y)$ plane where this statement is true.

Answer (score 4):

`Or` is a logical function giving `True` or `False` as an answer.  Perhaps, what you mean is curves for both `x^2 + y^2 == 1` and `x^2 + y^2 == 1/4`, in which case you should use (as suggested in a Comment by Nasser)

```
ContourPlot[{x^2 + y^2 == 1, x^2 + y^2 == 1/4}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]